# Iterating in React JSX

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am having a problem iterating in React jsx.

I want to make the code go

```
  value={('this.props.message.text1)}
  value={('this.props.message.text2)}
```

But I'm having trouble with the coding in the "value={('this.props.message.text1)}" part.

I want to do something like

```
value={('this.props.message.' + key)}
```

Below is my code;

```
constructor(){
   super();
   this.state = {
     message: {
         text1: "hello1",
         text2: "hello2"
     }
   }
 }

renderMessage(key){
    return (
      <div className="fish-edit" key={key}>
        <input
        type="text"
        value={('this.props.message.' + key)}
        onChange={this.props.handleChange}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }

render() {
   return (
     <div>
       {Object.keys(this.props.message).map(this.renderMessage)}
     </div>
   )
 }
};
```

Comment: I read your code, and I think you doesn't want `this.props.message` but `this.state.message`, do you ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically access object property using variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Answer (score 2):

use the squarebracket accessor notation, `value={this.props.message[key]}`